# Pulling the user's ID number from database (depending on the logged in user)

Tags: php, mysql, session

So my user's have access to changing their custom notify which is stored in my 'clients' database as 'notify'. I cannot seem to find out how to pull this information per session (as I don't want another user to change someone else's notify. Basically I'm trying to allow the user to click "Change Notify" in the navigation menu, then their notify (which I am guessing will depend on their session ID) shows up in the notify textbox, which will allow them to edit it accordingly.

**This is my session starting php**

```
<?php
include "includes/settings.php";
include "includes/database.php";
if(!isset($_SESSION))
{
    session_start();

echo "Welcome=" . $_SESSION['id'];
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    echo'
    <script language="javascript">
    window.location.href="index.php"
    </script>
    ';
}
$usersrow = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `users`");
$user_row = mysqli_fetch_array($usersrow);
$user_total = $user_row[0];

$clients = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `clients`");
$clients_row = mysqli_fetch_array($clients);
$clients_total = $clients_row[0];
$time_now = time("Y-m-d");

if(isset($_GET['deleteclient']))
{
    if($_GET['deleteclient'])
    {
        $id = strip_tags($_GET['deleteclient']);
        mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM `clients` WHERE `id` = '$id'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
    }
}

?>
```

**This is my update notify php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['upduser']))
{
    $clientnotify = $_POST['notifyVal'];
    $update_now = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `clients` SET `notify`='$clientnotify' WHERE `notify` = '".$client_notify."'");
    if($update_now)
    {
        echo'<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><div class="alert alert-success">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
        <strong>OK!</strong> Client successfully updated!.
        </div></div></div>';
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url="dashboard.php">';
    }
    elseif(!$update_now)
    {
        echo'<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><div class="alert alert-danger">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
        <strong>Fail!</strong> Client not update, Try again!.
        </div></div></div>
        ';
    }
}
?>
```

**This is my Custom Notify Form**

```
    <div class="panel panel-info">
    <form method="POST">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">SET CUSTOM NOTIFY</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body controls no-padding">
        <div class="row-form">
                <div class="col-md-3"><strong>Notify : </strong></div>
                <div class="col-md-9"><input type="text" required class="form-control" value = "<?php echo $client_notify; ?>" placeholder="Notify" name="notifyVal"/></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-success" name="updnotify">Set Custom Notify</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Store the user's ID in PHP session, then when they try to set / get their data, make sure the SQL has a condition that the row's user reference column has the same value as the stored user ID.

Comment: I'm not completely sure on how to do this. I'm trying to learn PHP while I go. When you say clients has a reference to the owning user, could you explain that a bit more? My users store this information in the database upon signup: (ID, USERNAME, PASSWORD, EMAIL, SKYPE, HOMETOWN, CAREER)

Comment: Well, you currently have 2 tables, `users` and `clients`. From what you've told us (I'm assuming) each row in the `clients` table is "owned" by a specific user. To maintain that relationship you have to have something that tells you that they belong together. Most often this would mean that e.g. `clients` would have a column like `user_id` that stores the ID (from the `users` table) of the user it relates to.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I don't think I do. Let me take a look.

Comment: Here's my clients and user tables. They both are using different ID's, which makes no sense now that I think about it.Users: http://image.prntscr.com/image/b36f7c36b19644668a67862f04577e53.png Clients: http://image.prntscr.com/image/36c9138dcaa0438db1fb83b28fd8fe06.png

Comment: It can make sense that each table has their own unique ID. But for relationships you'd want an extra column (on top of the tables unique ID) to make the link. Might be worth googleing about foreign keys.

Comment: Alright sounds good. I'll do that now. How would I link them together like you said?

Comment: Have a read around first and give it a go yourself. I suspect the stuff that comes up will explain a lot better than I can on SO.

Comment: Alright thanks for the help man, I'll give it a read!

Comment: Last comment, it's quite a big concept so don't worry if you don't "get it" straight away, but it is a massive part of database design and usage that will help you no end.

Comment: I'm reading about it now and I understand it. I didn't even know this was possible, so thank you for opening my eyes!